# Applying the Fourier transform to solve an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

We are learning about fourier transfrms in class and I was wondering about solving the following ODE using this method.

So, I want to solve the equation $u''(x)+u(x)=0$.
Now, it is clear that a solution is of the form $u(x)=Acos(x)+Bsin(x)$ for all $x\in R$ where A and B are constants.
So:
$$u''(x)+u(x)=0$$
So applying fourier transform
$$\mathscr F (u'')+\mathscr F(u)=0$$
$$(i \omega )^2\mathscr F (u)+\mathscr F(u)=0$$
$$-\omega^2\mathscr F (u)+\mathscr F(u)=0$$
$$(1-\omega^2)\mathscr F (u)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \mathscr F (u)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow u=0$$

Now although this is a solution, I dont understand why this method unable to produce the more general solution:
$u=Acos(x)+Bsin(x)$

Comment: For the second derivative you would actually get $(i\omega)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $(1-\omega^2)\mathscr{F}[u](\omega)=0$;

This tells you that $\mathscr{F}[u](\omega)$ has to be zero everywhere except $\omega = \pm1$. So we assume there exists a $a,b$ such that 
$$\mathscr{F}[u](\omega) = a\delta(\omega +1) +b\delta(\omega -1)$$
When you apply the inverse transform, you get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathscr F (u)=0$$ is wrong. And since it is not zero, you can divide the equation $$(i \omega )^2\mathscr F (u)+\mathscr F(u)=0$$ by it.

Comment: I dont see how $\mathscr F (u)=0$ could possibly be wrong. And even if you assume that $\mathscr F (u)$ is non zero, I dont see how dividing the equation by it could help. Any chance you could explain?

Comment: With (iw)^2 = -w^2 you have F(u)(1-w^2)=0. With F(u)!=0 you get 1-w^2=0

Comment: But isn't $\omega$ a variable, and so you can't just define it to be 1 or -1? Witch means F(u)=0 is the only possibility

Comment: No, with this approach you check, for which $\omega$ your assumption (sin $\omega x$ ...) fits